# Changing component property from another component

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have two components namely TripLegComponent.ts and EditScheduleComponent.ts.

```
export class TripLegComponent {

  showRate:boolean = false;

}
```

showRate is then being used in html template to control the visibility of input fields

TripLegComponent.html

```
 <div>
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class=" w-25 ">
      <mat-label class="vendor-label">{{ VENDOR_LABEL }}</mat-label>
      <input matInput [(ngModel)]="leg.vendor" class="trip-vendor-input" />
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field *ngIf='showRate' appearance="outline" class="ml-20 w-25 clr">
      <mat-label class="mode-label">{{ MODE_LABEL }}</mat-label>
      <input  readonly matInput [(ngModel)]="leg.mode" class="trip-mode-input" />
    </mat-form-field>


    <mat-form-field *ngIf='showRate' appearance="outline" class="ml-20 w-25 clr">
      <mat-label class="program-label">{{ PROGRAM_LABEL }}</mat-label>
      <input readonly  matInput [(ngModel)]="leg.program" class="trip-program-input" />
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field *ngIf='showRate' appearance="outline" class="ml-20 w-25 clr">
      <mat-label class="service-type-label">{{ SERVICE_TYPE_LABEL }}</mat-label>
      <input readonly matInput [(ngModel)]="leg.serviceType" class="trip-service-type-input" />
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
```

I want to modify 'showRate' property from another component i.e. from EditScheduleComponent.ts. So far i tried to use @viewChild to access the 'showrate' property of TripLegComponent.ts but it didnt work as i expected. Also, I tried service approach but I don't want to go that route since it required more testing efforts.

EditScheduleComponent.ts

```
export class EditScheduleComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(SuccessSnackbarComponent, { static: false })
  private snackbar: SuccessSnackbarComponent;

  @ViewChild(TripLegComponent, { static: false }) tripLegComponent: TripLegComponent;

  schedule: Schedule;
  isChanged: boolean = false;
  warningConfirmation: boolean = false;

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<EditScheduleComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: Schedule,
    private scheduleService: ScheduleService,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (!this.data.tripLegs || this.data.tripLegs.length === 0) {
      this.data.tripLegs = [new TripLeg()];
    }
    this.schedule = this.data;
    this.tripLegComponent.showRate = true;
  }
}
```

How can I set change the 'showRate' property of TripLegComponent from EditScheduleComponent.

what is the best approach that required minimum code changes?

Thank you

Comment: Is tripLeg a child of editSchedule? Or are they sibblings?

Comment: use angular behaviorSubject or Subject and based on that change your desired property, use shared service

Comment: or else you need to do input output based changes that will be way more code depending on your component structure